# How to set input change value dynamically for each input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default function App() {
 const [list, setList] = useState([
 {
  id: uuid(),
  name: "",
  isRemovable: true,
},
 ]);
const [newRowValue, setNewRowValue] = React.useState("");
 const [newRowIsRemovable, setNewRowRemovable] = React.useState(true);

 const removeItem = (removeId) => {
   setList((prevState) => prevState.filter(({ id }) => id !== removeId));
 };

const addNewRowItem = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

setList((prevState) => [
  ...prevState,
  {
    id: uuid(),
    name: newRowValue,
    isRemovable: newRowIsRemovable,
  },
]);
setNewRowValue("");
setNewRowRemovable(true);
 };
 return (
  <div className="app">
  
  {list.length > 0 ? (
    list.map(({ id, name, isRemovable }) => (
      <div className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body" key={id}>
        <>
          <form
            className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body"
            onSubmit={addNewRowItem}
          >
            <Input
              placeholder="Add a new row..."
              value={newRowValue}
              handleChange={(e) => setNewRowValue(e.target.value)}
            />
          </form>

          {isRemovable && (
            <Button
              color="danger"
              type="button"
              handleClick={() => removeItem(id)}
            >
              Remove
            </Button>
          )}
        </>
      </div>
    ))
  ) : (
    <div>(Empty List)</div>
  )}
  <form
    className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body"
    onSubmit={addNewRowItem}
  >
    <Button
      className="uk-margin-small-bottom"
      color="secondary"
      type="submit"
    >
      Add Row
    </Button>
  </form>
</div>
);
}
```

I am trying to add new row by clicking in add row but when user enters the value in input, the same value is getting applied.

How to make the each object input dynamically and push to array.

when i call `addNewRowItem` i can able to add new item but the value i entered for first input the same value is replicating for the new input as well

Comment: you are using the same state for each items value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the individual values of `list`, instead of using a single `state` property for all the rows. When you update any value, we need to create a new reference of `list` using `setList([...list])` after updating the value `onChange` event, this gives the expected output!

```
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';

import './style.css';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    {
      id: uuid(),
      name: '',
      isRemovable: true,
    },
  ]);
  const [newRowValue, setNewRowValue] = React.useState('');
  const [newRowIsRemovable, setNewRowRemovable] = React.useState(true);

  const removeItem = (removeId) => {
    setList((prevState) => prevState.filter(({ id }) => id !== removeId));
  };

  const addNewRowItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setList((prevState) => [
      ...prevState,
      {
        id: uuid(),
        name: '',
        isRemovable: newRowIsRemovable,
      },
    ]);
    setNewRowValue('');
    setNewRowRemovable(true);
  };
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {list.length > 0 ? (
        list.map((item, index) => (
          <div className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body" key={item.id}>
            <>
              <form
                className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body"
                onSubmit={addNewRowItem}
              >
                <input
                  placeholder="Add a new row..."
                  defaultValue={item.name}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    list[index].name = e.target.value;
                    setList([...list]);
                  }}
                />
              </form>

              {item.isRemovable && (
                <button
                  color="danger"
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => removeItem(item.id)}
                >
                  Remove
                </button>
              )}
            </>
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <div>(Empty List)</div>
      )}
      <form
        className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body"
        onSubmit={addNewRowItem}
      >
        <button
          className="uk-margin-small-bottom"
          color="secondary"
          type="submit"
        >
          Add Row
        </button>
      </form>
      {JSON.stringify(list, null, 4)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hgd5bx?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx&title=React%20Starter)